# Quick way of opening multiple files after reading input files in perl

Tags: perl

My input file (~5k lines) format looks something like this

```
foo0: users/user1/temp1 users/user2/temp1 4.0
foo1: users/user2/temp1 users/user4/temp2 users/user4/temp1 1.0
foo2: users/user1/temp3 users/user2/temp3 2.0
foo4: users/user4/temp5 users/user2/temp6 users/user1/temp1 users/user3/temp1 4.0
```

What my script needs to do is to look at each line, grab each of the paths, open file & check something inside based on it.

For ex: For line 1, the script has to open **user1**.txt and search for temp1 inside user1.txt and do something. Then go on to **user2**.txt and look for temp1 inside and do something.

For line 2: Open **users2**.txt and search for temp1; open **users4**.txt and search for temp2;  open **users4**.txt and search for temp1.

What's the quickest way to go about it. I currently open and close one by one, and that seems to take a long time. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How many files, how big are they? It makes a difference if you have three files each 10 lines long or a million each a million lines long.

Comment: Please answer Richard's question. If there is a limited number of `userN.txt` files then you could open all of them at once. At the very least you could arrange for all the queries on each file to be done together instead of closing and reopening them. Please give us more information

Comment: When things are slow, profile with something like [Devel::NYTProf](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Devel::NYTProf), discover the slow bits, and work on those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

while ( <> ) { 

    ## Remove last newline character.
    chomp;

    ## Split line with spaces and save paths (all strings but the first and
    ## last one).
    my @paths = split;
    @paths = @paths[ 1 .. $#paths - 1 ];

    ## For each path...
    for my $path ( @paths ) { 

        ## Split with a slash, get second field and try to open it. 
        my @elements = split m|/|, $path;
        open my $fh, q|<|, $elements[1] or die $!; 

        ## Read line by line searching for the third field of the path, do
        ## something if found. You can add a 'last' instruction if you wish.
        while ( my $line = <$fh> ) { 
            chomp;
            if ( $line =~ m/\Q${elements[2]}\E/ ) { 
                ## Do something;
            }   
        }   

        close $fh or warn $!; 
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is a solution equivalent to what the questioner said he had already: "I currently open and close one by one, and that seems to take a long time."  It still has the basic problem that is probably causing the slowness: opening and reading `user1.txt` many times if it occurs many times in the input.

Answer (score -1):

Well, on normal systems the hard disk data transfer speed is the limitation. But there are ways that might give you an edge:

#### Multithreading

If you fear your HDD might be idle while this program is running or if you read data from multiple physical drives, you might want to try multithreading. You should note that this *can* make your program run slower *(a)* if implemented wrong or *(b)* if your HDD reading heads have to jump around too much.

1. Open *n* pipes with the `pipe` function where *n* is the number of threads.
2. `fork` *n* times from the main ("*boss*") thread.

   1. Each worker thread closes all unrelated pipes
3. The boss thread reads your input file and pipes each command to a different process *in turn*. That way, all worker processes have an equal workload.
4. The worker threads do your searching etc.

If you haven't done multithreading with `fork` before, this solution won't work for you.

And, as mentioned above, this is somewhat unlikely to induce a positive result *except* when your computations on each file are expensive (when the time doing computationes / searches is comparable to the time spent reading) If your script drains much CPU and you have multiple processors, this might help.

#### Come up with a better algorithm

- What and how do you search for in each file? Do you just match a single regexp against each line and then execute some code? What code? Is the regexp overly complex?
- Can you use some heuristic to skip a certain part of the file?
- Have you tried [`Tie::File`](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/Tie-File-0.98/lib/Tie/File.pm)? This avoids loading the file into memory which may help.
- Have you **benchmarked** your script? See this [tutorial on perl.com](http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/06/25/profiling.html) for an introduction. What parts run slow?
- Can you decrease the algorithmic complexity of your program? I.e.: are you iterating twice over any file? That may be suboptimal.

Comment: I don't think multi-threading is a very good first suggestion here.  Granted, we don't know very much about the problem, but it's a rare case when this would be needed.  And it adds a lot of complexity and many pitfalls.